# Migrations Script Generator in Azure Pipeline fails attempting to use .net 8

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, entity-framework-migrations, .net-7.0, .net-8.0

I have been successfully using the [Entity Framework Core Migrations Script Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pekspro.pekspro-efcore-migration-script-generator) in my Azure DevOps YML pipelines but today it broke with the following message which I'm pretty sure is related to the release of .net 8.

```
Installing version undefined of dotnet-ef as global tool.
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe tool install --global dotnet-ef
C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2b213b08-cdae-40fe-ab24-770b2badf581\restore.csproj : error NU1202: Package dotnet-ef 8.0.0 is not compatible with net7.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0) / any. Package dotnet-ef 8.0.0 supports: net8.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0) / any
The tool package could not be restored.
```

Does anyone know how to force this tool to use .net 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried installing version 7 of `dotnet-ef` explicitly, which doesn't take a direct dependency on .NET 8?

Either by manually installing it from a script task:

```
- pwsh: dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 7.*
```

Or by adding the explicit version as an input to the task:

```
- task: efcore-migration-script-generator-task@1
  inputs:
    eftoolversion: 7.*
```

Or of course by adding `UseDotNet@2` to install .NET 8:

```
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    version: 8
```

Comment: I fixed this using the 2nd suggestion - by adding "eftoolversion: 7.0.14" to the list of inputs. I'd tried something similar myself but hadn't correctly guessed the name of the parameter. I'd love to know where @jessehouwing you found the documentation such that you knew the name was "eftoolversion". But many thanks for fixing my problem in any case.

Comment: I looked at the source in the git repo

Comment: Check out `index.ts` and `task.json` here: https://github.com/pekspro/EF-Migrations-Script-Generator-Task/tree/master/efcore-migration-task/efcore-migration-script-generator . I searched for the `dotnet tool install` command to see what options were programmatically passed in.

Comment: I agree this is a solution, but adds future burden in having to maintain either the tool version, or the SDK version going forwards. I also can't remember having had this issue with 7.0 when it was release (and we were still building on 6.0 agents). I've opened a github issue with the SDK team to get to the bottom of this: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/36904

Comment: The dotnet-ef version 7 is based on .NET 6, as such it's compatible with .NET 6 and above. dotnet-ef version 8 is based on .NET 8 and such requires *at least* dotnet 8.

Ideally the task you're using would take care of this and would have issued a major update, instead of silently changing the dependencies.

Comment: To make versioning easier, you could set the version to `7.*`, which should always pick the latest version 7, but would not upgrade to version 8.